# Automation Anywhere Metabots

Tags: c#, automationanywhere

I have a classlibrary (c# dll) that has list of string as a parameter,how to pass arguments to this list using AA variables(only type of variables available in AA are-value,password,array in **metabot**).I have tried passing array but this does not work(no output is produced).
Can someone just try this example an share me the solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As far as I know** this is not possible. They way I resolved this is to concatenate the entire `array` in AA, resulting in 1 string. Using some kind of delimiter.

E.g. `['foo']['bar']['far']` will become `'foo;bar;far'`.

Make the dll accept a string instead of an array and split it inside of the C# method.

*If somehow it is possible to directly pass an array as parameter, I would love to hear it.*

Comment: ya i to went with the same approach but thats not always feasible if the data generated is dynamic and the delimiter itself is present in data.Thanks for the comment

Comment: I recall using the delimiter '_DE-LI-MI-TER_' once due to this issue. It's not ideal, but it works. Even better would be to use a UUID e.g. ' c3b9095e-40e1-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b'. You can generate these online.